# Adding ternary numbers in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Good evening.
I'm trying to do my homework and im stuck. 
The purpose of the program is to add two numbers in ternary system. I don't know why, but i doesn't work, like i expect to.
I'm adding 2 numbers. 45 and 27 which equals 72, which is 2200 in ternary system and program gives me 20000.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a[4];
int b[4];
int carry=0;
int result[5];


a[0]=1;
a[1]=2;
a[2]=0;
a[3]=0;

b[0]=1;
b[1]=0;
b[2]=0;
b[3]=0;

for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{

    if(a[i]+b[i]+carry==6)
    {
    result[i]=2;
    carry=0;
    }
    if(a[i]+b[i]+carry==5)
    {
    result[i]=1;
    carry=2;
    }
    if(a[i]+b[i]+carry==4)
    {
    result[i]=1;
    carry=1;
    }
    if(a[i]+b[i]+carry==3)
    {
    result[i]=1;
    carry=0;
    }
    if(a[i]+b[i]+carry==2)
    {
    result[i]=0;
    carry=2;
    }
    if(a[i]+b[i]+carry==1)
    {
    result[i]=0;
    carry=1;
    }
    if(a[i]+b[i]+carry==0)
    {
    result[i]=0;
    carry=0;
    }


}
result[4]=carry;
for(int j=4; j>=0; j--)
{
    cout<<result[j];

}
cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's some redundant branching you have. I guess it should be chained with `if-else`.

Comment: Now it gives 84. Else if doesnt work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two things confused.

First, as DWright already noted, you confused your digits, you were actually adding 0021 and 0001.

Second, you mixed up the digit and the carry, e.g. if the sum is 6, then the carry should be 2 and not the digit at that position.

While I agree that you should rewrite your program as DWright suggested, here is a version of your code that should do what you wanted it to do which might help you understand your mistakes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[4];
    int b[4];
    int carry=0;
    int result[5];


    a[0]=0;
    a[1]=0;
    a[2]=2;
    a[3]=1;

    b[0]=0;
    b[1]=0;
    b[2]=0;
    b[3]=1;

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {

        if(a[i]+b[i]+carry==6)
        {
        result[i]=0;
        carry=2;
        }
        else if(a[i]+b[i]+carry==5)
        {
        result[i]=2;
        carry=1;
        }
        else if(a[i]+b[i]+carry==4)
        {
        result[i]=1;
        carry=1;
        }
        else if(a[i]+b[i]+carry==3)
        {
        result[i]=0;
        carry=1;
        }
        else if(a[i]+b[i]+carry==2)
        {
        result[i]=2;
        carry=0;
        }
        else if(a[i]+b[i]+carry==1)
        {
        result[i]=1;
        carry=0;
        }
        else if(a[i]+b[i]+carry==0)
        {
        result[i]=0;
        carry=0;
        }


    }
    result[4]=carry;
    for(int j=4; j>=0; j--)
    {
        cout<<result[j];

    }
    cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

edit: I also changed the branching to else if. Since you changed carry in your chain, it was possible that you would go into several branches in one run before even though they looked exclusive, e.g if `a[i]+b[i]+carry == 6` you set `carry` to 0 (falsely, but there are also examples in the right code) making `a[i]+b[i]+carry == 4` (the carry must have been 2 before), so the function would have entered that branch as well.

Answer (score 2):

Don't have a c compiler installed at the moment, but something like this should work.  I'm going to give you a sketch, not the full thing.  Note how I flipped the sequence of digits in `a` and `b`, which means the `i = 0` starts with the least significant digit,  which is what you want for the `carry`s.  Also, note how I initialized `result` to all zeroes, which is a safety measure.

```
int a[4];
int b[4];
int carry=0;
int result[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};


a[3]=1;
a[2]=2;
a[1]=0;
a[0]=0;

b[3]=1;
b[2]=0;
b[1]=0;
b[0]=0;

int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    sum = a[i] + b[i] + carry;
    if (sum > 2) {
        //do something with carry
        //do something with sum
    } else {
        //make sure carry is 0
    }
    result[i] = sum;
}
//set result[4] to carry--but what if carry is > 2 (say if you were adding more than 2 numbers?)

//todo: make this general, so that it is not dependent on having arrays of width 4 for input and 5 for result.
```